# how can i find $f(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a real function with $f(0)=0 ,$ differentiable for $x \neq0 $ and $f'(x)= \frac{e^x}{3f^2(x)+2f(x)+1}$. How can I show that there exists a $x_0, 0<x_0<2 $ s.t. $f(x_0)=1$?

---

I’ve already shown that $f^3(x)+f^2(x)+f(x)=e^x-1$ from multiplying the given fraction with the denominator and intergrating. Also I have shown that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0)=1$.

Now to prove that there exists a $x_0 , f(x_0)=1$: we already know $f(0)=0 $, and I tried to find $f(2)$ so I can use the intermediate value theorem but got nowhere. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be $f^2(x)$ instead of $2f(x)$

Comment: right right i miss clicked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that there exists no $x_0\in [0,2]$ with $f(x_0)=1$. Since $f(0)=0$, the intermediate value theorem implies that $f(x)<1$ for all $x\in[0,2]$. This means that

$$3f(x)^2+2f(x)+1 < 3+2+1 = 6,$$
and so $$f'(x) = \frac{e^x}{3f(x)^2+2f(x)+1} > \frac{e^x}{6}$$ for all $x\in [0,2]$. But since we can integrate this inequality, we get that
$$f(2) = f(0)+\int\limits_0^2 f'(x)dx > f(0) + \frac{1}{6}\int\limits_0^2 e^xdx = 0 + \frac{e^2-1}{6} >1,$$
which of course is a contradiction to the initial assumption.

EDIT: Using Maple, I calculated an explicit formula for $f$:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{6}\left(-80+108e^x+12\sqrt{48-120e^x+81e^{2x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{4}{31}\frac{1}{\left(-80+108e^x+12\sqrt{48-120e^x+81e^{2x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}-\frac{1}{3},$$
so to really answer your question: $f(2) \approx 1.428993842$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be the way.Using your conclusion.
$f^3(x) + f^2(x) + f(x) + 1 = e^x$
Let there be some $x = x_o $ such that $f(x_o) = 1$.So putting $x =x_o$ in the above equation we get $e^{x_o} = 4$.Now since $e^x$ is a strictly increasing function.So as $1 < 4 < e^2$ then $e^0< e^{x_o} < e^2$.So $0< x_o <2$.

Comment: That seems really smart but I do not understand if that guarantees us that $x_0$ is between 0 and 3 . Also since we just "Let " a $x=x_0$ exist s.t $f(x_0)=1$ Are we sure that it exists?

Comment: See as in the question it is given $f(x_o) =1 $.I am just taking taking any arbitrary x which satisfies the equation but not presuming at the same time that it must belong to(0,2) . It is only when we use the property of e^x that we conclude that it must stay with 0 and 2.Now your doubt that does such $x_0$ exists or not then you can think that in this way that since$ f(x)$ is related to $e^x$ and as $e^x$ is continuos so f(x) must be also continuos thus giving us a value at $x_o$

Comment: Alright thank you so much ! You really helped me out

Comment: Glad you got it.

Comment: I don't think your approach is working... Assuming that an x exists so that f(x) = 1 and then using this assumption to show that there also has to exist an x in [0,2] with f(x) = 1 is logically not the same as proving that there exists an x in [0,2] with f(x) = 1.